# React Native (Android) - Stacknavigator above other view

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm beginning in React Native development.

I've spend many hours on something but I'm still blocked.

I have a "header" view and under the view, a Stack navigator and inside a tab navigator.

[image]

When I open the stack navigator (with the Login Button), I would like to put the new view above the "header", without hiding him to avoid ugly effect when the new view appears. 
Here an example when I put a negative margin top on the stacknavigator, but it stays behind the header
[image]

Is there any other way to do this properly ?
Thanks.

For information, I've started from the React Native boilerplate "Pepperoni App Kit",  added my custom header before the AppNavigator, and hidden the headers on the Tab navigator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having header under View, you should have use headerMode:'screen' option with StackNavigator. You can control the visibility of header under each sub navigator using the navigation options.

Here is sample snippet

```js
export const Root = StackNavigator(
  {
    Tabs: {
      screen: HOViewPager,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: "Title",
        header: <Header />,
      },
    },
    login: {
      screen: Login,
      navigationOptions: {
        headerMode: "none",
        header: null,
      },
    },
    imageoverlay: {
      screen: HOImageOverlay,
      navigationOptions: {
        headerMode: "none",
        header: null,
      },
    },
  },
  {
    mode: "modal",
    headerMode: "screen",
  }
);
```

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the late answer, I was not working last week. Thanks, I initially tried this but without success, I'll try again, thanks !

Comment: Does the "<Header />" respect a specific format ? I tried with a very simple header with just a text, but have a "React is not defined" on this line. Should I have explicit header left/right/title in this header ? If yes, can you please show me a sample for the header ? Thanks.

Comment: <Header /> was a custom component that I imported to use as header. You can ignore it if you do not want any header. If you want to use Text try below.   navigationOptions: {
  title: 'Title',
  header:<Text> header text</Text>
}

Comment: Oh thanks again, it didn't worked because I was on RN 0.42.. I just updated to 0.44 and everything works fine. Just didn't noticed that initially because my project was recent.